# Maps showing blank screen when build in release mode

Tags: ios, google-maps, dictionary, flutter, apple-maps

I am building an application where I need to use Flutter maps, everything work as expected, however if I make a build through Jankins for release mode then for some reason the maps on iOS displays blank. I have another page where the same widget is opened in a full page and there it works. My thoughts are that placing google maps in SingleChildScrolView causes the issue. Below I am attaching the source code.I have replaced the SingleChildScrolView with with list view where I pass all widgets as children but the effect is the same, the map is displayed in debug mode but when building through Jankins the map is blank , but on another page the map widget is working as expected.
Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am banging my head for hours.

Regards

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Model _model;

  DashboardPage(this._model);

  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  List<Dossier> _dossiers = List();

  _DashboardPageState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
        _header(StringResources.dashboardTitle),
        _mapWidget(),
        _header(StringResources.myFiles),
        _listWidgets()
      ],),
      );
  }

  Widget _mapWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: DossierMap(
        compassEnabled: false,
        model: widget._model,
        onDossierMapViewCreated: _onMapWidgetCreated,
        onDossierInfoWindowTap: _selectedMarker,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _listWidgets() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Dossier>>(
        initialData: [],
        stream: widget._model.dossierService
            .loadDossiers(widget._model.loginService.token)
            .catchError((e) {
          if (widget._model.loggedIn) {
            widget._model.forcedServerLogout();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return LoginPage(
                  model: widget._model,
                  errorText: "",
                  onLoggedInCallback: (context) => Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DossiersPage(widget._model))),
                );
              },
            ));
          }
        }).asStream(),
        builder: (_context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            _dossiers = snapshot.data;
            return snapshot.data.length != 0
                ? _buildList(snapshot.data)
                : _noDossierContentWidget();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return _progressIndicator();
          } else {
            return _progressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }

  Widget _header(String text) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color(ColorResources.darkGray)),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 12, 0, 12),
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(text,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.white))),
      ),
   );
  }

  void _onMapWidgetCreated(dynamic controller) {
    controller.setMarkers(_dossiers);
  }

  Widget _buildList(List<Dossier> dossierList) {
    return Container(
        color: Color(ColorResources.dividerColor),
        height: 400,
        child: ListView.separated(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade300, height: 1.5),
            itemCount: dossierList != null ? dossierList.length : 0,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>  DossierListItem(
                  dossier: dossierList[index],
                  fromSearch: true,
                  widget: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                    size: 30,
                    color: Color(ColorResources.gray),
                  ),
                  onListItemClickListener: () =>
                      onListItemClicked(dossierList[index]),
                )));
  }

  void onListItemClicked(Dossier dossier) {
    _selectedDossier(dossier);
  }

  Widget _progressIndicator() {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }

  Widget _noDossierContentWidget() {
    return Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            StringResources.noOwnedFiles,
            softWrap: true,
            maxLines: 3,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.caption,
          ),
        ));
  }

  void _selectedMarker(DossierCluster cluster) async {
    if (cluster.isCluster) {
      Dossier selected = await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 24.0),
              title: Center(child: Text(StringResources.selectFile)),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                  children:
                      dossiersFromCluster(cluster, onDossierListMarkerClick),
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(StringResources.cancel),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                )
              ],
            );
          });
      if (selected != null) _selectedDossier(selected);
    } else {
      _selectedDossier(cluster.getFirst);
    }
   }

  List<Widget> dossiersFromCluster(
      DossierCluster cluster, Function onDossierListMarkerClick) {
    List<Widget> widgets = List();
    for (int i = 0; i < cluster.size; i++) {
     Dossier dossier = cluster.get(i);
      widgets.add(DossierListItem(
        dossier: dossier,
        fromSearch: false,
        widget: Container(),
        onListItemClickListener: () => onDossierListMarkerClick(dossier),
      ));
    }
    return widgets;
  }

  void _selectedDossier(Dossier dossier) {
     widget._model.setDossier(dossier);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DossierDetailsPage(widget._model)),
    );
  }

  void _openFullSize() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FullScreenMapPage(widget._model, _dossiers),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onDossierListMarkerClick(Dossier dossier) {
    widget._model.setDossier(dossier);
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DossierDetailsPage(widget._model)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you added your API key in your release build and is it restricted? And just to clarify, where exactly does your map load vs. where does it not? Have you tried other devices, browsers...?